# Neo4j with Puma - is there a recommended setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, neo4j, puma

I am looking to switch from Unicorn to Pums for my RoR app using Neo4j.
Are there any recommended config and settings?

Comment: I don't know of anything special but if you have any issues we can take a look.  I just switched the asset_portal example application ( http://github.com/neo4j-examples/asset_portal ) to Puma and it's working fine (in development) so far.  I've been using MRI so I don't know if the database calls to Neo4j count as IO (I imagine they do, we're using Faraday so all of that should be taken care of)